# How to rsync files between two remotes which share the same host?

Tags: drush, deployment

I've two remotes: `@remote.dev` and `@remote.test`.

I'm trying to rsync between these two remote Drupal instances by:

```
$ drush -vy rsync @remote.dev @remote.test
```

But rsync complains that:

> The source and destination cannot both be remote.

Both remotes are on the same machine, but they're using different path.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can't use two remotes for rsync, but because these two instances are on the same host you may use `drush dd` to return the filesystem path and use it as a source.

In example (syncing webroot):

```
$ drush -vy @remote.test rsync `drush dd @remote.dev` @self
```

or syncing just files folder:

```
$ drush -vy @remote.test rsync `drush dd @remote.dev:%files` @self:%files
```

This will work if you're using the same credentials for both.